# PythonまたはRでクロス集計をしたい

Tags: python, r

PythonまたはRで以下のCSVファイルを読み込んで、クロス集計を行いたいのですが、うまくいきません。
男性┗肉のようにクロス軸を二次元にする事は出来るのですが、一次元にする事が出来ません。

**CSVデータイメージ**
[image: SVデータイメージ]

****クロス集計イメージ****
[image: クロス集計イメージ]

ChatGPTで質問したところ以下の回答でしたが、主力イメージが意図した結果になりませんでした。
ご教示いただけますと幸いです。宜しくお願いいたします。

**[image: 出力イメージ]**

```py
# CSVファイルの読み込み
df = pd.read_csv('ファイル名.csv')

# クロス集計の実行
cross_tab = pd.crosstab(index=[df['性別'], df['設問1']],
                        columns=df['設問2'], margins=True, margins_name='合計')

# 列の順番を設定
column_order = ['合計', 'TOYOTA', 'HONDA', 'BMW']
cross_tab = cross_tab.reindex(columns=column_order)

# 行の順番を設定
index_order = [('全体', ''), ('男性', ''), ('女性', ''), ('肉', ''), ('魚', ''), ('合計', '')]
cross_tab = cross_tab.reindex(index=index_order)

# 結果の出力
print(cross_tab)
```

Answer (score 1):

性別と設問1を別個に集計して結合します。

```py
import pandas as pd

# CSVファイルの読み込み
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# クロス集計
cross_tab = pd.concat([
    df.pivot_table(index='性別', columns='設問2', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0),
    df.pivot_table(index='設問1', columns='設問2', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)])
cross_tab['合計'] = cross_tab.sum(axis=1)
cross_tab.loc['全体'] = cross_tab.sum()
cross_tab.rename_axis('性別/設問1', inplace=True)

# インデックスの順序を変更
column_order = ['合計', 'TOYOTA', 'HONDA', 'BMW']
index_order = ['全体', '男性', '女性', '肉', '魚']
cross_tab = cross_tab.reindex(index=index_order, columns=column_order)

# 結果の出力
print(cross_tab)

# 設問2       合計  TOYOTA  HONDA  BMW
# 性別/設問1                          
# 全体           8       4      2    2
# 男性           2       1      1    0
# 女性           2       1      0    1
# 肉             2       1      1    0
# 魚             2       1      0    1
```

Comment: metropolis様

ご回答ありがとうございます！！
クロス集計を分割して、最後にマージする方法をとるんですね！
非常に勉強になります。

ご教示いただいた記述を理解し、軸の追加、他の設問でもクロス集計できるようにします。（設問が30ほどあるため）

ネットでクロス集計の方法を調べても情報量が少なく苦戦していたため、
回答いただき道筋が見えました。重ねてありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

既に解決済みですが，御参考として `R` の記述例（`tidyverse` パッケージを使用）を示します。
手順としては，`count()` と `pivot_wider()` を使って設問2の全体集計と2個のクロス集計（性別\設問2，設問1\設問2）を作り，これらを縦に結合してから「合計」列を追加しました。また，最初に `df` の各列を `factor()` で変換しているのは `levels` で表示順を設定するためです。なお，実行環境は「macOS 13.2.1(M1), R 4.2.3, tidyverse 2.0.0」です。

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv('data.csv', show_col_types=FALSE)

df <- df |>
    mutate(性別=factor(性別, levels=c('男性', '女性')),
           設問1=factor(設問1, levels=c('肉', '魚')),
           設問2=factor(設問2, levels=c('TOYOTA', 'HONDA', 'BMW')))

df1 <- count(df, 設問2) |>
    pivot_wider(names_from=設問2, values_from=n) |>
    mutate(区分=c('全体'), .before=1)

df2 <- count(df, 性別, 設問2) |>
    pivot_wider(names_from=設問2, values_from=n, values_fill=0) |>
    rename(区分=性別)

df3 <- count(df, 設問1, 設問2) |>
    pivot_wider(names_from=設問2, values_from=n, values_fill=0) |>
    rename(区分=設問1)

df4 <- rbind(df1, df2, df3) |>
    rowwise() |>
    mutate(合計=sum(TOYOTA, HONDA, BMW), .after=1)

print(as.data.frame(df4))
```

```
  区分 合計 TOYOTA HONDA BMW
1 全体    4      2     1   1
2 男性    2      1     1   0
3 女性    2      1     0   1
4   肉    2      1     1   0
5   魚    2      1     0   1
```

Comment: Delft View様
回答いただきまして、ありがとうございます！！
Rでクロス集計する方法も把握しておきたかったので非常に助かります。

クロス軸に対して設問が10問あった場合、
df4で定義を設問分する必要がありそうですね。

変数とループ処理できる方法がないか上記を参考に調べてみます！